# Create an index on a column of a CollectionTable using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, data-modeling

Suppose I have the following entity which models a subscriber and uses a `CollectionTable` to model a list of subscriptions like so:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBSCRIBER")
public class Subscriber {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "PERSON_ORG_SUBSCRIPTIONS",
                     joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "PERSON_ID" ),
                                     @JoinColumn( name = "ORG_ID", referencedColumnName = "ORG_ID" ) } )
    @Column(name = "SUBSCRIPTION_NAME")
    protected Set<String> _subscriptionNames;
}
```

So this creates a table with columns for `PERSON_ID`, `ORG_ID` and `SUBSCRIPTION_NAME`.

I'm trying to create a database index on the `SUBSCRIPTION_NAME` column. But if I put the following annotation on `_subscriptionNames`:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index( name="subscription_idx", columnNames={"SUBSCRIPTION_NAMES"} )
```

I get an exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find logical column name from physical name null in table SUBSCRIBER
```

I also tried using the `org.hibernate.annotations.Table` annotation on the `Subscriber` entity, but there does not seem to be a way to have it reference the `PERSON_ORG_SUBSCRIPTIONS` table.

I'm using Hibernate 3.5.3 and PostgreSQL 9.0.

Comment: Have a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400169

Comment: Eventualy I gave up on making some indexes on Hibernate 4.2 and previous. Hibernate 4.3 will support JPA 2.1 which supports `indexes` right inside `@JoinTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the column with name "SUBSCRIPTION_NAME" present in the table SUBSCRIBER?

Are you planning to create index on table from the code? You should propably use hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create